# nginx load balancing redirect 404

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing

I have 3 servers. The first server have nginx as load balancing. Second and third servers have apache. In my nginx conf I have the following :

```
upstream backend  {
  server ec2-54-148-248-231.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
  server ec2-54-148-34-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass  http://backend;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}
```

The problem is : when I open the first server it redirects me to the second or third one but I can't load any relative URLs (ex: css or js files) inside my site and all links return a 404 error.

can you try my load balaning server on line url => http://ec2-54-148-96-241.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Why the hell are you putting nginx on top of apache ?

Comment: i follow this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing but i do not know exactly why i select apache to be under nginx.i think i select apache as normal thing for me because i use php.

Comment: Then rethink you architecture.

Comment: in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination. he use nginx on top of apache

Comment: I personally don't see apache mentionned anywhere but in comments. This apache layer is absurd. It's like putting a ferrari overa a tug and saying it will go faster. Nginx should be used directly as a reverse proxy to applications, this apache layer breaks the whole purpose of nginx.

Comment: Ok so it seems it's not clear why you keep a try files statement. Thougt you tried to serve static files with nginx. Why do you set this directive along proxy pass ?

Comment: Try this can you try my load balaning server on line url => http://ec2-54-148-96-241.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
this really was happen all static return 404 and also if you click on about link you will see 404

Comment: i try separate my static on alone location but the problem still found

Comment: When i comment this line try_files $uri $uri/ =404; load balancing not working as expected just server # 2 is requested but also there some files missing and returned 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that nginx with round-robin or least-connected load balancing, each subsequent client’s request can be potentially distributed to a different server. so on my site after make first request for ex => http://ec2-54-148-96-241.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/site/index
then make request http://ec2-54-148-96-241.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/assets/f352c4d6/css/bootstrap.css it go to another server but for assets f352c4d6 not found on another server so return 404.

solution:
you must use ip_hash; with nginx load balancing to keep the same server for one ip
also you may be use leas_connect to distribute user to least server traffic.